# What is the correct way to extend TypeScript definitions in a 3rd party library?

Tags: typescript

I'm using TypeScript 4.5.5

There's an interface `DvaInstance` in a 3rd party library `dva`, existing `index.d.ts` for this library looks sth. like:

```js
export interface DvaInstance {
  // ...
}

export {
  connect, connectAdvanced, useSelector, useDispatch, useStore,
  DispatchProp, shallowEqual
} from 'react-redux';
```

A field named `_store` exists in JavaScript but is missing in this interface, and now I want to extend this interface to include this field.

So I went ahead and created a `dva.d.ts`:

```js
declare module 'dva' {
  interface DvaInstance {
    _store: import('redux').Store;
  }
}
```

Then this field (`_store`) became available. However, `tsc` started to complain when I do `import { connect } from 'dva'`:

```
Module '"dva"' has no exported member 'connect'.
```

Looks like my module declaration overrides dva's, and declaration merging is not working as I expected.

I searched online and a lot of articles (including [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)) use `import` statement. So I tried again:

```js
import { DvaInstance } from 'dva';

declare module 'dva' {
  interface DvaInstance {
    _store: import('redux').Store;
  }
}
```

This time, both `import { connect } from 'dva'` and `_store` field works, but `tsc` complains that `'DvaInstance' is already declared in the upper scope`.

My questions are:

- A top level `import` or `export` makes the `.d.ts` file a non-ambient module, how come the types in it are still available without explicitly importing it in other files (`import 'dva.d.ts'`)?
- What is the correct way to extend TypeScript definitions in a 3rd party library without unexpectedly overriding existing TypeScript definitions?

Comment: If the problem is that your module shadows the third-party module of the same name, surely the easiest thing to do would be to just give your module a different name?

Comment: @kaya3 My intension is to extend 3rd party libraries' type definitinos, if I use a different name, it defeats my purpose.

Comment: Can you provide a GitHub repo or codesandbox?

Answer (score 4):

To properly trigger [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html), I should use `import 'dva'` instead of `import { xxx } from 'dva'`.

`dva.d.ts`:

```
import 'dva'; // Trigger declaration merging

declare module 'dva' {
  interface DvaInstance {
    _store: import('redux').Store;
  }
}
```

However there's still one question unanswered: a top level `import` or `export` makes the `.d.ts` file a non-ambient module, how come the types in it are still available without explicitly importing it in other files (`import 'dva.d.ts'`)?